# how to store vector of vector by index

Tags: c++, stl, vector

Hi I have to store the below mentioned information in a vector of vectors format...

```
 vector <vector <int>> ph;
 vector<int> p, q;
 p.push_back(1);
 p.push_back(2);
 p.push_back(3);

 q.push_back(10);
 q.push_back(20);
 q.push_back(30);
 q.push_back(40);
```

Now instead of using:

```
 ph.push_back(p);
 ph.push_back(q);
```

I want to use:

```
 ph.at(0)=p
 ph.at(1)=q
```

(This is the error that I am getting when I am using this: terminate called after throwing an instance of 'std::out_of_range'
  what():  vector::_M_range_check)

The reason why I want to store it this way is....later I want to access the elements of a particular vector identified by its index i.e. 1 or 0.

For example I wish to access ph[0].size() i.e the size of p...identified by its index. That is, I want to perform the same operation as we are able to do in the case of simple arrays in c++ i.e. store the data in that array at a particular index and access the data from a particular index.

Comment: Just reverting tagging changes for the heck of it...?  The topic of your question is not about the `std::` namespace in any relevant way...thinkaboutit.  You could tag it "size" or "getting" or "the" or "element" or "access" and that wouldn't be useful either.

Comment: @HostileFork furthermore, `stl` is probably irrelevant here, since it is more than likely that the `vectors` in question are C++ standard library vectors, not STL ones.

Comment: @juanchopanza Touche.  It pains me to think that even with a full semantic tag system, with knowledge-based hierarchies, we probably won't get it perfect...probably has something to do with quantum physics.  :-P  http://commontag.org/Home

Answer (score 2):

You are getting the error because when you instantiate the vector of vectors, it has size 0, and the `at()` method is allowed to do bound checks and raise an exception.

If you want to access by index like that then you are better off with an [std::map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) or [std::unordered_map](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_map). That makes the index independent of the order of insertion:

```
std::map<int, std::vector<int>> MapOfVectors;
std::vector<int> p, q;
// fill vectors
MapOfVectors[1] = q;
MapOfVectors[0] = p;
```

Otherwise, you would have to make sure your vector of vectors is large enough to insert elements by index:

```
// instantiate vector with size 2. You can insert p and q by index. (0, 1) only
vector<vector<int>> ph(2);
```

Or, resize it after creation:

```
vector<vector<int>> ph;
ph.resize(2);
```

Comment: Please have a look at the post http://stackoverflow.com/a/6320285/1354510 Here the person is trying to access the size of a vector of vector of edges...I doubt how it is done...I mean how is it possible to do it during storing. Also thanks a lot for helping...please be kind to clear my doubt

Comment: @user1354510 in that example, at the top of the dijkstra function vector `d` is initialized to be size `n-1`, in a way similar to my second code snippet.

Answer (score 0):

When you define `vector<vector<int>> ph` the vector `ph` is empty. The `.at()` member function does bounds checking and correctly throws an exception when you try to write to non-existing elements.

You could do `ph.resize(2)` so that indices 0-1 would then be valid or just use `push_back` like you do currently.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to use:

```
ph.at(0)=p  ph.at(1)=q
```

That attempts to access indices past the end of the array, hence the exception.

> The reason why I want to store it this way is....later I want to access the elements of a particular vector identified by its index i.e. 1 or 0.
>
> For example I wish to access ph[0].size() i.e the size of p...identified by its index. That is, I want to perform the same operation as we are able to do in the case of simple arrays in c++ i.e. store the data in that array at a particular index and access the data from a particular index.

You can achieve this by first filling the outer vector with empty inner vectors:

```
vector<vector<int> > ph(2);
```

Here, the `2` says to construct the outer vector to contain 2 default-constructed elements (themselves `vector<int>`).

Alternatively, you can use:

```
vector<vector<int> > ph;
ph.resize(2);
```

After you've done that, it will be safe to access the elements to store non-default-constructed values.  That means the following won't throw:

```
ph.at(0)=p;  ph.at(1)=q;
```